# mixed within-subject/between-subject design: how to build a model for power analysis

Tags: mixed-model, experiment-design, statistical-power

We have the data for three different treatments (A,B,C) in between-subject design. The means are correspondingly (X,Y,Z).
Now because reviewers insist, we need to re-run it in such a way that each item is exposed first to treatment T1, and then to treatment T2:

A->A,

A->B

A->C

B->C

C->B

etc.
Where B->C for instance means that an item is exposed to treatment B and then to treatment C.

We need to figure out how large each group should be (using our X,Y,Z as priors).
But what I am struggling with is how this model should look like (to run simulations). Because I assume that there will be a treatment difference within-subject (B->C for example). But also there will be a between-subject difference (t0 difference between subjects assigned to B->C and C->B, for example).

How would you approach that?